# How can I publish a video stream at red5pro in android?

Tags: android, http, rtsp, red5, red5pro

I already have a http video stream coming from an IP camera in my android hotspot. I want to publish that stream in a red5pro server or in another media service. How can I do that?

The red5pro sdk examples only use a camera from android. I want to use a http stream came from IP camera connected in my android hotspot.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us some code.

Comment: Do you want to visualize the stream and then forward it or just forward it as soon u you get it ?

Comment: Yes Simon. I just want to forward it as soon I you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a player like VideoJS, set the tech order to prefer HTML5 over Flash and then ensure that you're using the appropriate URL for the stream.

An example URL patter would look something like this:

http://server:5080/live/hls/streamName.m3u8

Note that it ends in .m3u8, has the right port and uses the context and app names.

For more information please see our documentation page.  Please let me know if this helps you or if anything isn't clear.
https://www.red5pro.com/docs/